# Get value from list with colon in variable identifier

Tags: python, variables, facebook-opengraph, identifier

I have a list that I get from the function called 'get_meta_tags', and I need to retrieve the 'og:image' value

```
def get_meta_tags(url):
    out={}
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    m = re.findall("property=\"([^\"]*)\" content=\"([^\"]*)\"",html)
    print m
```

This is what I get when I run 'print m'

```
[('og:image', 'http://i.imgur.com/MemV51q.jpg')]
```

I don't know how to get the "og:image" value since the identifier has a colon, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is list of tuples (in this case, the list has only one element):

```
>>> m
[('og:image', 'http://i.imgur.com/MemV51q.jpg')]
```

It is not a dictionary and accessing the "value" (i.e. second element of each tuple) requires searching through every element and comparing the first element of each tuple with your query.

However, you can easily convert this into an actual dictionary:

```
>>> dict(m)
{'og:image': 'http://i.imgur.com/MemV51q.jpg'}
```

Now you can access it the usual way:

```
>>> dict(m)['og:image']
'http://i.imgur.com/MemV51q.jpg'
```